# Auto mount USB stick on plug-in without UUID

Tags: pi-3, usb, mount

So, I'm making a media center. I need the Pi to auto mount ANY USB stick I plug in. No mater what filesystem (vfat,NTFS,ext). I searched everywhere, and couldn't find anything that works.
Well, usbmount partially works. I can't get it to mount NTFS and make flash drives accessible to all users.

Running Raspbian Jessie Lite on RPI3

Comment: Why are you not using an out of the box media centre like OpenElec or something similar? They have all the quirks ironed out.

Comment: Because I want to learn more about Linux

Comment: The best solution I found for this was https://github.com/Ferk/udev-media-automount based on the recommendation in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev#Mounting_drives_in_rules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I found a solution that works quite well. Big thanks to avanc and his [udev rule](https://github.com/avanc/mopidy-vintage/wiki/Automount-USB-sticks) that makes this possible. I also modified it so that it could mount up to 4 flash drives at the same time (it can be increased if needed).

## Requirements

1. Install pmount if not installed `sudo apt-get install pmount`
2. This script mounts drives to `/media/usb*`, so make sure those folders aren't occupied. **If you want a cleaner look, don't create any folders.**

## Udev rule

1. Create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/usbstick.rules`
2. Insert:

   ```
   ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usbstick-handler@%k"
   ```
3. Save and close

## Systemd service

1. Create file `/lib/systemd/system/usbstick-handler@.service`
2. Insert:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Mount USB sticks
   BindsTo=dev-%i.device
   After=dev-%i.device

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cpmount /dev/%I
   ExecStop=/usr/bin/pumount /dev/%I
   ```
3. Save and close

## Mount script

1. Create file `/usr/local/bin/cpmount`
2. Insert:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if mountpoint -q /media/usb1
   then
      if mountpoint -q /media/usb2
      then
         if mountpoint -q /media/usb3
         then
            if mountpoint -q /media/usb4
            then
                echo "No mountpoints available!"
                #You can add more if you need
            else
                /usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -w --sync $1 usb4
            fi
         else
            /usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -w --sync $1 usb3
         fi
      else
         /usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -w --sync $1 usb2
      fi
   else
      /usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -w --sync $1 usb1
   fi
   ```
3. Give execute permission to the (root) user: `chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/cpmount`
4. Save and close

## Finish

Reboot your RPi and test.

## NOTES

- You can change pmount parameters, but these allow anyone r/w access to usb.
- The amount of mountpoints can be changed.
- Thanks to avanc for his [udev rule and service](https://github.com/avanc/mopidy-vintage/wiki/Automount-USB-sticks).

Comment: This works well, except the Note (1) says this allows r/w access, but the "-r" option to pmount forces r/o. change each of the four lines above to "-w" to give full read-write access.

Comment: Also you missed a `0` on `/usr/bin/pmount --umask 00 -noatime -r --sync $1 usb4` ?

Comment: I copied and pasted this script and it failed with errors. You need to add an extra `0` to the `umask` flag and an extra `-` to the `noatime` flag for your first `else` statement there, so the entire statement should be `/usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -r --sync $1 usb4`.

Comment: @pauliucxz;  Maybe also mention in your article that the file `cpmount` must have executable permission set for the user `pi` (it doesn't have that set by default, only `rw` permissions are set by default): `sudo u+x cpmount` (inside `/usr/local/bin`).  It was not working for me just because of that reason.  Now it works perfect...

Comment: Don't create the systemd service in `/lib/systemd/system/`, but use `/etc/systemd/system/` instead. The former path is intended for services provided by installed packages, while the latter can be used by the system administrator for its own services.

Comment: @GeertVc your comment worked wonderfully for me, thanks! but you miss the term "chmod" in `sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/cpmount`

Comment: @xor: You're absolutely correct.  Good catch!  Sorry about that...

Comment: @GeertVc i added your suggestion to the procedure in the answer

Answer (score 8):

My version based on the [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66324/73358) above:

## Systemd service

Put:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount USB sticks
BindsTo=dev-%i.device
After=dev-%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/automount %I
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pumount /dev/%I
```

in `/lib/systemd/system/usbstick-handler@.service`

## Mount script

Put:

```
#!/bin/bash

PART=$1
FS_LABEL=`lsblk -o name,label | grep ${PART} | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ -z ${FS_LABEL} ]
then
    /usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -w --sync /dev/${PART} /media/${PART}
else
    /usr/bin/pmount --umask 000 --noatime -w --sync /dev/${PART} /media/${FS_LABEL}_${PART}
fi
```

In `/usr/local/bin/automount`, and then:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/automount
```

Reboot.

The mount points/folders names will be in the format of `/media/<PartitionLabel>_<sdxy>`. In case a partition has no label, it will just be `/media/<sdxy>`.

So, I normally label my USB drives with their capacity. e.g. 8G, 16G. When I plug in multiple USB disks with the same label, I can still distinguish them as, for example:

```
/media/500G_sdb1
/media/500G_sdc1
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the `--sync` option. The write speed was very slow on my USB external drive

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found for this is using the [pmount](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/pmount) service.

I used the normal process to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install pmount
```

The only thing you need to worry about is if you already have regular directories in /media/pi with the same names as a USB drive.  If you do, it will append a numeral as it mounts the drive.

For instance, if you have a directory named /media/pi/STICK and then you install a flash drive of the name STICK, you will find it has mounted it at /media/pi/STICK1

This can happen if you have had the stick installed but not properly ejected as it was removed, before installing pmount.

When that happened to me, my programs happily kept writing to my STICK but when I pulled it out and plugged it into another computer, it was empty.  It was writing to the directory, and not to the device.

So I renamed the directory to /media/pi/temp, installed pmount, mounted STICK and copied the contents of temp to /media/pi/STICK

Then when I eject it, and verify on another computer, it is doing precisely what I intended.

Comment: I installed it, but it doesn't do anything. When I plug in my falsh drive nothing happens. I checked /media and it's empty. I also checked lsblk and it wasn't mounted anywhere.

Comment: It will show up under /media/pi  - use file manager to drill down into there and look that way..  It should also prompt you for your password when it is installed.  If it doesn't, then perhaps it is not recognizing that flash drive at all.  Another way you can see it is    df -h

Comment: fdisk -l shows the flash drive, if I type "pmount /dev/sda1 /media/pi/STICK" it mounts successfully. But df -h doesn't see it. I tried many drives, and they still wouldn't auto mount.