# usbmount runs correcty but mount does not show up

Tags: pi-3, usb, mount

I have installed `usbmount` on Pi 3 "Raspbian GNU/Linux Debian 10 (buster)".  After rebooting or pugging in a USB hard-drive, I see this in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 25 15:44:03 gbox usbmount[538]: loaded usbmount configurations
Jul 25 15:44:03 gbox usbmount[538]: trying to acquire lock /var/run/usbmount/.mount.lock
...
Jul 25 15:44:03 gbox usbmount[538]: acquired lock /var/run/usbmount/.mount.lock
...
Jul 25 15:44:03 gbox usbmount[538]: /dev/sda1 contains filesystem type ext4
Jul 25 15:44:03 gbox usbmount[538]: mountpoint /media/usb0 is available for /dev/sda1
Jul 25 15:44:03 gbox usbmount[538]: executing command: mount -text4 -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sda1 /media/usb0
...
Jul 25 15:44:04 gbox usbmount[538]: executing command: run-parts /etc/usbmount/mount.d
Jul 25 15:44:04 gbox usbmount[538]: usbmount execution finished
```

**`/media/usb0` is not mounted**

I can however sudo to root and run the command from the syslog and it works fine:

`mount -text4 -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sda1 /media/usb0`

**`/media/usb0` is mounted**

The log mentions `/etc/usbmount/mount.d` after the mount command.  There is only one file in there so I run it by hand:

`/etc/usbmount/mount.d/00_create_model_symlink`

**`/media/usb0` still mounted**

Any idea why `usbmount` seems to work but does not mount the drive?

Answer (score 1):

Updated /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service

```
Change: PrivateMounts=yes
To: PrivateMounts=no
```

see: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100375/1016

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.