# Updating python code with usb

Tags: usb

I have a folder in the pi/home directory with python code. Is there a way to update (replace) these files by using one of the usb ports? I would like to be able to plug in the usb, reboot the pi, if there is a usb drive on boot, copy and replace the files in pi/home folder with the ones on the usb then automatically power back down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

First configure your Raspberry Pi to auto-mount USB Storage Devices (guide [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/auto-mount-usb-stick-on-plug-in-without-uuid)).

Then create a script that checks the folders under `/media/` where the mounted USB stick would be. If it finds your scripts, replace the old ones with the new ones.

Configure your script to run at boot by editing your `/etc/rc.local` (guide [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md))

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.