# Has there been an update in how to install pmount to Raspberry Pi OS lite?

Tags: usb, update, mount

I am working on this project: https://www.dannyromano.com/raspberry-pi4b-dual-screen-video-looper/

Who references the installation procedure by pauliucxz here: [Auto mount USB stick on plug-in without UUID](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/auto-mount-usb-stick-on-plug-in-without-uuid?newreg=272a879f6d984aaf94125330e3172c13)

But it does not seem to work on newer versions of Pi OS Lite.

The project requires the OMXplayer which was discontinued after Buster 2021 05 28 release. Which is also the oldest version that runs on my Pi4 board (it's newer, only bought it a few months ago).

Following these instructions does not work. Has something changed in the way this must be done?

Comment: WRT Bookworm not using X, there is an option to enable it (instead of the new Wayland compositor) in `raspi-config`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using a version of Buster on this. Pmount should be able to install on Buster, correct? Is there a reason why the instructions given on the stackexchange post linked above from 6 years ago wouldn't work anymore?

Comment: My point was you don't have to use Buster if the issue is only whether there's an X11 server available, because this is just a minor matter of configuration (and you may have been misinformed about that by the last set of comments) -- but I notice that OMXplayer or lack there-of is also a problem.  I know nothing about pmount, but a problem with your question is that you casually refer to something not working but you do not go into any detail about exactly what you tried and exactly what happened (by "detail" I mean something beyond "doesn't work")...

Comment: ..People do not like to bother with that kind of question because 1) They tend to necessitate wasting everyone's time trying to drag details out of you, and 2) They often include someone making a specific recommendation and you saying, "Oh I already tried that", which would have been clear if you were specific enough in the first place. The fact that you linked a set of instructions doesn't really help, because it begs the question that you actually followed them correctly (turns out to be the problem in many cases) and places the onus on the people you are asking for help to do that research.

Comment: Anyway, WRT to the answer from the old question, I see nothing there that should be incompatible with later versions of the OS (including bookworm) except pmount itself; udev has not changed much and other than a possible typo ('pumount') in the systemd service file, it should also work.  But again, you've said nothing about what exactly "didn't work" means.

Comment: Gotcha! I'll see if I can run it on bookworm. What's happening with pmount is that I follow the instructions, no errors are recorded, but then when I check to see if USBs are mounting, nothing is. This project using pmount to make sure that USB files show up in a reliably named directory so they can be loaded into the player, no matter which slot the drive is plugged into. The "pumount" is also a very good catch! I had wondered about that when setting it up, but figured that so many people accepted this as the answer, that any typos would be cleared out. I'll give it a shot! Thank you

Comment: Hmmm. I'm thinking now that the pmount quest is a form of [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).  What you really want to do is stated in the last comment -- get mounts from a specific USB device that are consistent, so you can rely on the location of their content -- is really pretty simple and very common.  I and probably most other linux users use secondary storage this way. You can do this with a single line in `/etc/fstab` and perhaps some symlinks or bind mounts.

Comment: Put the nitty gritty details (exactly what paths are involved, what filesystem is used on the USB drives, etc.) into a new question.

Comment: I have corrected the potential pumount typo, and it has had no effect. After completing the steps, there is still no location media/usb1 created. I also notice that ls -lha does not show anything called pmount as having installed? It seems like something should show up, right?

Comment: @goldilocks, yes, it is a bit of an XY, but REALLY the solution that I'm after is that I want to be able to play two different videos, simultaneously and synced, on my pi4 at the same time as part of a stage show. Only one person in the world has built a solution for this that's anywhere close to what I'm trying to do (the first link in the post) and he built it this way. I'm attempting to follow verified steps from someone who has actually made a functional piece of software that's working out in the wild, but failing to do so, and I'm not sure why.